# Share 3G internet connection

Tags: linux, 3g, lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share internet in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/162058/share-internet-in-linux)

Hi, I new in linux and I would like to share my 3G intenet connection using a ethernet cable, but I dont know how to doit, and I have problems with the network cards order.

1st Computer (Lubuntu Linux):
3G Modem, Wired Network Card

2nd Computer (Windows XP):
Wired Network Card

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firestarter](http://www.fs-security.com/) here is an [article](http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/archive/2008/11/13/how-to-do-internet-connection-sharing-on-linux/view) to someone writing about the exact same thing you are trying to do and another [article](http://www.fs-security.com/docs/connection-sharing.php) describing it in more detail. You would need a crossover network cable to connect them directly or a regular cable and a hub/switch to share it out to multiple targets or if you don't have a crossover cable.

Comment: Most network cards (starting with 100BASE-T and Gigabit) support automatic crossover (Auto-MDIX); crossover cables aren't necessary anymore.

Comment: Did not know that :)